# Is it possible to get coordinates from network plots?

Tags: r, igraph, sna, gplots, statnet

I'd like to reproduce a network graph with the same (or close) layout.  I know that igraph has the tkplot.getcoords() function.  I'd like to copy/get/set.seed a set of vertex coordinates based on the results of gplot, which is the SNA package's plotting function.

I've looked for places to do this but haven't found anything.  Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: Added a reproducible example.  I'd like to have all 9 plots have the same layout without using igraph::tkplot.

```
library(statnet)

set.seed(101)
mydata <- data.frame(from = sample(1:15,10,replace = T),
          to = sample(1:5,10,replace = T))



par(mfrow=c(3,3), mar=c(1,1,1,1))
k <- 1:9
for (i in 1:9) {
  gplot(network(mydata),main = paste('Iteration',k[i])) 
}
```

[image]

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provided a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with some sample input data and a clear description of the desired output.

Comment: @MrFlick, thanks.  I've added the example above.  Any thoughts on how to capture the coordinates of Iteration 1 and apply them to all other iterations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the plot to an object and then pass that to the argument `coords =` within `gplot`.

```
library(statnet)

set.seed(101)
mydata <- data.frame(from = sample(1:15,10,replace = T),
                     to = sample(1:5,10,replace = T))


l <- gplot(network(mydata))
par(mfrow=c(3,3), mar=c(1,1,1,1))
k <- 1:9
for (i in 1:9) {
  gplot(network(mydata),main = paste('Iteration',k[i]), coord = l) 
}
```

If you inspect 'l' you can see that it is a matrix of x, y coordinates.

```
> l
               x          y
 [1,] -0.4123840 -13.450699
 [2,]  6.1177559  -8.707917
 [3,]  0.5330693 -10.061580
 [4,] -1.5359554 -11.325280
 [5,]  2.7944671 -10.988359
 [6,]  5.1480964 -10.557675
 [7,] -1.7695806  -5.636370
 [8,]  2.2053996  -4.643251
 [9,]  1.8990660 -13.347872
[10,]  2.1035474  -8.824222
[11,] -3.3637096 -10.181900
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks very much.